# Set overlapping two PictureBox

Tags: c#, image, picturebox, overlapping

I have problem with creating two overlapping `PictureBox`es. I write my code like everyone told me but I have some problem:

First: background is black (why?)
Second: why tree appears two times?

EDIT:
Image http://i48.tinypic.com/2llnfrq.png (stack overflow had problem)

This is sample code for test.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AllowTransparency = true;

        MyPictureBox pb1 = new MyPictureBox();
        MyPictureBox pb2 = new MyPictureBox();

        pb1.Size = new Size(64, 64);
        pb1.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        pb1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        //pb1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

        pb2.Size = new Size(64, 64);
        pb2.Location = new Point(52, 20);
        pb2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        pb1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\...\\Graphics\\Grounds\\woda1.png");
        pb2.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\...\\Graphics\\Objects\\tree1.png");

        panel1.Controls.Add(pb2);
        panel1.Controls.Add(pb1);
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}


class MyPanel : Panel
    {
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
                return cp;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }

        public MyPanel()
        {

        }
    }

class MyPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
            return cp;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    public MyPictureBox()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you plz provide a screenshot of your form? Thx.

Comment: You say that tree appears two times, but we don't really know what you mean exactly. Show an image, or something.

Comment: I tried this quickly (with your code), and it worked fine...

Comment: I have problem with uploading image, I tried on other PC
maybe it's stackoverflow issue

Comment: If you C#, you'll see only one tree. Sorry, couldn't hold it :)

Comment: @marsze how exactly does your image look like?